# Integer linear problem (ILP) example, with 3 constraints and an additional restriction?

Tags: inequality

Say I have the following Integer Linear problem:

$x_1 \geq$ 0 No. of Item A

$x_2 \geq$ 0 No. of Item B

$x_3 \geq$ 0 No. of Item C

$x_4 \geq$ 0 No. of Item D

Maximize z = 2$x_1$+3$x_2$+4$x_3$+15$x_4$

Subject to: $x_1$ + $x_2$ + $x_3$ + $x_4$ $\leq$ 100 ($\alpha$)

With ($\alpha$) being the inequality for the amount of time to produce each product. (i.e. 100 hours allowed)

How would implement the following additional restriction

($\beta$) If any of item B is made then item A, C and D are not made.

And write it up as a model including this additional restriction (For $z_i$ = 1 for i $\in$ [1,2,3,4] if any of item N $\in$ {A,B,C,D} is made - and 0 if not)

How would I write it up now? Thanks you.

Comment: Hi ! Share any code you have so far :)

Comment: Sorry I just realised I am ok with writing the code - I just wanted to know if I was to implement $\beta$ how would I do that. So purely a Mathematic question here. The way I see it is if you have $z_1$ = 1 then $z_2$ = $z_3$ = $z_4$ = 0 and also if $z_1$ = 0 then $z_2$,$z_3$,$z_4$ $\in$ {0,1} - but how would you add that as another line to the problem. I hope it is ok to ask math question on here.

Comment: Well, not exactly. If it is a strictly mathematics question you have to migrate it :)

Comment: Oh I am very sorry @Sektor , I am new to this how does it migrate. Thank.

Comment: If you add the Mathematica code to the question then very likely people can suggest how to modify it to handle the discrete conditions.